# Prove that any connected cover of $S^1$ of finite degree is homeomorphic to $S^1.$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Assume that any connected and compact $1$-manifold is homeomorphic to either the unit circle $S^1$ or the unit interval $[0, 1].$ Prove that any connected cover of $S^1$ of finite degree is homeomorphic to $S^1.$

I don't have any idea how to proceed? Could anyone share some ideas?

Thanks for investing your valuable time on my question.

Comment: Have you tried showing that any connected covering of $S^1$ of finite degree is a compact $1$-manifold?

Comment: @VincentBoelens$:$ No I don't know this fact.

Comment: @VincentBoelens$:$ Could you please give me some suggestion as to why the covering space has to be compact?

Comment: If $p\colon E\to S^1$ is a covering map, then there is a finite cover $U_1,\ldots, U_n$ of $S^1$ such that $p$ is trivial over $U_i$ for all $i$, since $S^1$ is compact. Assume WLOG that the $U_i$ are homeomorphic to intervals. Then use the assumption to show that $E$ is sequentially compact, which is enough since it is a manifold.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p\colon E\to B$ be a covering map of finite degree with $B$ compact. I claim that also $E$ is compact. Let $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be an open cover of $E$ and for each point of $b\in B$ choose a trivializing neighborhood $V_b$ such that the sheets of $p^{-1}(V_b)$ are contained in some member of $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ (here we use that $p$ is of finite degree). By compactness of $B$ there are $b_1,\ldots, b_n$ such that $B\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{b_i}$. Now again by finiteness of the covering $p^{-1}(V_{b_i})$ is covered by finitely many elements of $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$, hence also $E = \bigcup_{i=1}^n p^{-1}(V_{b_i})$.

Now apply this to $B=S^1$ and use that in this case $E$ must be a $1$-dimensional manifold since $p$ is a local homeomorphism and $E$ cannot be homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, since $[0,1]$ cannot cover $S^1$.

Comment: What are trivializing open sets and how to get hold of them? Also why $[0,1]$ does not cover $S^1\ $? What I can see is that there is no covering of $S^1$ of finite degree if the covering space were simply-connected. So in our case I am done!

Comment: Maybe you know it as an evenly covered neighborhood. It is an open set $U$ such that there is a homeomorphism $p^{-1}(U)\cong U\times F$ over $U$. Any covering map is a local homeomorphism, but $[0,1]\to S^1$ is not a local homeomorphism. It fails to be one at the boundary points.

Comment: If I understood it correctly then a property is said to hold locally in topology if given a point and given a neighbourhood around that point there exists a further sub-neighbourhood on which the property holds. So according to this definition a function $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ is said to be a local homeomorphism if given a point $x \in X$ and given a neighbourhood $U_x \ni x$ there exists a further sub-neighbourhood $U_x \supseteq V_x \ni x$ such that $f\ \big \rvert_{V_x}\ \colon\ V_x \longrightarrow f(V_x)$ is a homeomorphism. Am I right?

Comment: No, you need to additionally require that $f(V_x)$ is open in $Y$. Another way to see it is to note for any covering $p\colon E\to B$ the cardinality of the fiber is constant on the path components of $E$, but this is not true for $[0,1]\to S^1$.

Comment: $:$ But you didn't give reasoning to any of the facts you mentioned. Why doesn't there exist any local homeomorphism from $[0,1]$ to $S^1\ $? Why doesn't the cardinality of the fiber remain constant for any map from $[0,1]$ to $S^1\ $? I am well aware of the fact that exponential map is not a covering map from $[0,1]$ to $S^1$ and I think you literally argue in the same direction. But then the question arises what are the possible continuous maps from $[0,1]$ to $S^1\ $?

Comment: Ok, you want to allow for any map $p\colon [0,1]\to S^1$. Let $z=p(0)$ and $U$ be a neighborhood of $z$ that is evenly covered. By shrinking we can assume $U\neq S^1$. Finally, let $V\subset p^{-1}(U)$ be the sheet containing $0$. Then there is $\epsilon >0$ such that $[0,\epsilon)\subset V$ is an open subset of $V$ and also $[0,\epsilon]\subset V$. Since $p$ restricted to $V$ is a homeomorphism onto $U$, $p([0,\epsilon))=p([0,\epsilon])\setminus \{p(\epsilon)\}$ is an open subset of $U$, which is impossible.

Comment: What I think is the following $:$ I know that any local homeomorphism is continuous and open. From here I think it is easy to show that composition of finitely many local homeomorphisms is also a local homeomorphism. Therefore in order to show that $[0,1]$ and $S^1$ are not locally homeomorphic it is enough to show that $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb R$ are not locally homeomorphic. Now if $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb R$ were locally homeomorphic there exists $a \gt 0$ such that $[0,a)$ is homeomorphic to an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R.$ Since $[0,a)$ is connected so $U$ must be an open interval...contd

Comment: But there exists no open interval which is homeomorphic to $[0,a)$ as removing $0$ from $[0,a)$ still yields a connected set but no matter what point we remove from an open interval it becomes disconnected. This should wrap things up!

Comment: Yes, that was what I was getting at. It is impossible for $[0,\epsilon)$ to be homeomorphic to an open subset of $S^1$. No need to involve $\mathbb{R}$. Also, cardinality of fibers is constant because of fiber transport. If $p\colon E\to B$ is a covering and $b_1,b_2\in B$, then any path $\alpha$ from $b_1$ to $b_2$ yields a map $\alpha_\ast\colon p^{-1}(b_1)\to p^{-1}(b_2)$ independent of the path homotopy class. Also, if $\beta$ is another path starting at $b_2$, then $\beta_\ast\circ \alpha_\ast = (\alpha\ast\beta)_\ast$, so that the fiber transport map must be bijective.

Answer (score 0):

We can resolve this problem without any manifold theory. Just for the interest; I realise your original question focuses on the manifold perspective. We can use covering space theory instead.

Take a locally and globally path connected space $X$, which is also semilocally simply connected. Let $\upsilon:(U,u_0)\to(X,x_0)$ be a universal covering map, where $U$ is a suitable simply connected space. It can be shown that all covers of $X$ are isomorphic to quotients $U\times F/m_R\times\varrho$ where $F$ is a discrete space, $\varrho$ is a given *right* action of $\pi_1(X;x_0)$ on $F$ and $m_R$ is a certain canonical right action of $\pi_1(X;x_0)$ on $U$. The connected covers are precisely those for which $\varrho$ is transitive. Moreover, the resulting cover is $|F|$-sheeted. This is covered in reasonable detail by Hatcher.

In particular take $X=S^1,U=\Bbb R$ and some connected finite $n$-sheeted cover of $S^1$. It will be isomorphic to a quotient $\Bbb R\times[n]$. Identifying $\pi_1(S^1,1)\cong\Bbb Z$ in the canonical way, the action $m_R$ in this instance is $k\cdot x=x+k$. If $\varrho$ is a transitive action of $\Bbb Z$ on $[n]=\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, it is generated by some transitive permutation $\tau$ of $[n]$ and these are precisely the $n$-cycles. Up to a relabelling of the integers, any $n$-sheeted connected cover of $S^1$ is then isomorphic to some quotient of $\Bbb R\times[n]$ which identifies $(x,j)\sim(x',j')$ iff. $x'-x$ is an integer and $x'-x=j'-j\bmod n$. Clearly we can choose a single 'stick' $\Bbb R$ as a set of representatives, whereupon two elements are equal iff. they differ by a multiple of $n$. It follows any connected $n$-sheeted cover of $S^1$ is isomorphic to the cover $\Bbb R/n\Bbb Z\cong S^1\to S^1,z\mapsto z^n$.

Comment: If you only want to think about the action abstractly consider this: If $G$ is the fundamental group of $X$, then $G$ operates on any covering $p\colon E\to X$ via deck transformations, thus sending $p$ to the fiber $F$ yields a functor from the category of connected coverings to the category of transitive $G$-sets with equivariant maps. The classification of coverings states that under suitable conditions this is an equivalence of categories. It is easy to see that $\pi_1(E)$ is the isotropy group of $F$.

Comment: For $S^1$ everything is easy, since up to isomorphism the only $\mathbb{Z}$-set with $n$-elements is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, hence there is only one $n$-sheeted covering, which is $S^1\to S^1, z\mapsto z^n$.